# Rails Postgres query to exclude any results that contain one of three records on join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This is a hard problem to describe but I have Rails query where I join another table and I want to exclude any results where the join table contain one of three conditions.

I have a `Device` model that relates to a `CarUserRole` model/record. In that CarUserRole record it will contain one of three `:role` - "owner", "monitor", "driver". I want to return any results where there is no related CarUserRole record where `role: "owner"`. How would I do that?

This was my first attempt -

```
Device.joins(:car_user_roles).where('car_user_roles.role = ? OR car_user_roles.role = ? AND car_user_roles.role != ?', 'monitor', 'driver', 'owner')
```

Here is the sql -

```
"SELECT \"cars\".* FROM \"cars\" INNER JOIN \"car_user_roles\" ON \"car_user_roles\".\"car_id\" = \"cars\".\"id\" WHERE (car_user_roles.role = 'monitor' OR car_user_roles.role = 'driver' AND car_user_roles.role != 'owner')"
```

**Update**

I should mention that a device sometimes has multiple CarUserRole records. A device can have an "owner" and a "driver" CarUserRole. I should also note that they can only have one owner.

**Anwser**

I ended up going with @Reub's solution via our chat -

```
where(CarUserRole.where("car_user_roles.car_id = cars.id").where(role: 'owner').exists.not)
```

Comment: so what is the problem with this query you are getting result with `owner` or not getting resuult at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what its grabbing to be honest. When I run `.collect {|x| x.owner.present?}` at the end though most of the results are true, they should all false.

Comment: try .collect {|x| x if !x.owner.present?} to check where there is no owner

Comment: @MoamenNaanou that returns mostly false, but theres still a few trues in there

Comment: I'm sorry I left out a key detail. Please see the update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the car_user_roles table can have multiple records with the same car_id, an inner join can result in the join table having multiple rows for each row in the cars table. So, for a car that has 3 records in the car_user_roles table (monitor, owner and driver), there will be 3 records in the join table (each record having a different role). Your query will filter out the row where the role is owner, but it will match the other two, resulting in that car being returned as a result of your query even though it has a record with role as 'owner'.

Lets first try to form an sql query for the result that you want. We can then convert this into a Rails query.

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM car_user_roles WHERE role='owner' AND car_id = cars.id);
```

The above is sufficient if you want devices which do not have any car_user_role with role as 'owner'. But this can also give you devices which have no corresponding record in car_user_roles. If you want to ensure that the device has at least one record in car_user_roles, you can add the following to the above query.

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM car_user_roles WHERE role IN ('monitor', 'driver') AND car_id = cars.id);
```

Now, we need to convert this into a Rails query.

```
Device.where(
     CarUserRole.where("car_user_roles.car_id = cars.id").where(role: 'owner').exists.not
).where(
     CarUserRole.where("car_user_roles.car_id = cars.id").where(role: ['monitor', 'driver']).exists
).all
```

You could also try the following if your Rails version supports `exists?`:

```
Device.joins(:car_user_roles).exists?(role: ['monitor', 'driver']).exists?(role: 'owner').not.select('cars.*').distinct
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it looks like the first SQL query you posted works! I'm having issues with the Rails queries though. I'm running Rails 4.0.12, would that prevent me from running both Rails queries you posted?

Comment: I think Rails 4.0.12 supports all the methods that I used (exists?, distinct). Can you tell me the exact error that you're facing with the rails queries?

Comment: I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cars.role does not exist`. I do have a Car model but I wasn't using that for this problem, could that be the problem? I was curious as to why you had "cars"

Comment: Oh, I used 'cars' since the sql query you posted had the table name as 'cars'. You can change 'cars' to the actual table name in the rails queries. Same goes for the 'Device' model. Change it to the actual class/model name.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that, Device is a single table inheritance of Car. Either way I think theres another problem with the Rails query unfortunately. The SQL one works but I'd really like to figure it out in Rails if possible.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try out the rails queries. I'll edit the answer and comment here if I figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'll let you know if I find anything too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124067/discussion-between-reub-and-ryan-grush).

Answer (score 1):

- Select the distinct cars

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT (cars.*) FROM cars
  ```
- Use a LEFT JOIN to pull in the car_user_roles

  ```
  LEFT JOIN car_user_roles ON cars.id = car_user_roles.car_id
  ```
- Select only the cars that DO NOT contain an 'owner' car_user_role

  ```
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM car_user_roles WHERE cars.id = car_user_roles.car_id AND car_user_roles.role = 'owner')
  ```
- Select only the cars that DO contain either a 'driver' or 'monitor' car_user_role

  ```
  AND (car_user_roles.role IN ('driver','monitor'))
  ```

Put it all together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (cars.*) FROM cars LEFT JOIN car_user_roles ON cars.id = car_user_roles.car_id WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM car_user_roles WHERE cars.id = car_user_roles.car_id AND car_user_roles.role = 'owner') AND (car_user_roles.role IN ('driver','monitor'));
```

Edit:

- Execute the query directly from Rails and return only the found object IDs

  ```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).collect { |x| x['id'] }
  ```